# RTL EditText broken pointer issue in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-inputtype

In rtl layout, edittext **pointer** gets broken in android devices.

I have an application which supports English and Arabic languages. In that the edit text fields with input type number is having this issue mainly. While entering numbers in edit text field, the pointer will break into two halves as shown in the image.

This is the xml code of the edittext.

```
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_budget"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/white_background_theme_border"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/choose_budget"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/black" />
```

[image: pointer break]

Have someone experienced this issue. Is there any fix for the same. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this

**Layout**

```
<EditText>
    ... 
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textDirection="rtl"
</EdiText>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    ...
    android:supportsRtl="true">
    ...
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply add this line

```
 android:layoutDirection="ltr"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `android:inputType="number"` , setting `android:inputType="phone"` worked in my case. As I just wanted to type number in my edit text.

Following is my EditText from xml :

```
<EditText
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textDirection="rtl"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:hint="abc"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:id="@+id/myNumber"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColorHint="#767676"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android:textDirection="ltr" left to right
android:textDirection="rtl" right to left
```

It makes text direction to the chosen side. If your input value is Latin characters I highly recommend you ltr (for Arabic). but labels are positioned as its nature (like Arabic right, English left)